# Alert users of max question limit BEFORE writing the question!

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, post-ban

This has happened to me a lot of times and it drives me crazy, after writing a very detailed question, taking snapshots of my app behavior, pasting code and such I click submit and I get the message "You have exceed the 3 question limit per day" or something similar.

I never have any idea how many questions I've asked or how near I am the daily (or monthly) limit so it drives me crazy to spend time writing the question and only after finishing being told I cannot ask it. Would it be possible to show a message on top of the question form so I don't type the question?

Comment: It's a reasonable request, so +1, but, somebody has to say it: if you're running into the question limit repeatedly, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Your draft should be saved, shouldn't it? So you can just submit it tomorrow? Or is that not what happens (I've never run into the limit)

Comment: I think it is saved. I don't know if by the browser or the site. But still it would be nice if you knew beforehand

Comment: The question limit is 6 per day and 50 per month.

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro Drafts are normally saved by the site - stuff I've started writing on my phone appears on my laptop etc. Admittedly that's experience based on answers rather than questions. ymmv.

Comment: Solid request , easy to implement

Comment: @DanielFischer For what it's worth, [~40% of Lisandro Vaccaro's 500+ questions are upvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A535967+votes%3A1) compared to [<5% downvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/535967/liso22?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=19) so whatever they're doing wrong isn't reflected in the primary quality measure, i.e., votes.