# Alert users of question ban on iOS before asking a new question

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, asking-questions, post-ban

When using the web version of Stack Exchange, if a user has reached their account's question limit, (aka: their account has been question banned), they will see an error message before they can type and submit their question.

[image: Desktop error message for edit ban]

The iOS app should follow this behavior, rather than informing the user *after* they have typed and submitted their question.

[image: iOS error *after* writing post]

Comment: Related although unclear if these are relevant to the app so not sure if duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165499/alert-users-of-max-question-limit-before-writing-the-question?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/please-warn-about-exceeding-50-question-limit-prior-to-asking-a-new-question.

Comment: @JasonC The linked posts are about the daily question limit. This is different than a question ban.